# Destroy game objects one at a time, with time interval

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, gameobject

I have created a procedurally generated 'tiled floor' in unity3d, using a block prefab asset and script as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Wall : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject block;
    public int width = 10;
    public int height = 10;
    public int timeDestroy = 1;
    List<GameObject> blockList = new List<GameObject>();
    

    void Start(){

        for (int y=0; y<height; ++y)
        {
            for (int x=0; x<width; ++x)
            {
                Vector3 offset = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
                GameObject hello= (GameObject)Instantiate(block, transform.position + offset, Quaternion.identity);
                blockList.Add(hello);
            }
        }
        
        StartCoroutine(SelfDestruct());

    }

    void Update()
    {
        SelfDestruct();
    }
    
    IEnumerator SelfDestruct()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeDestroy);
    
        Destroy(blockList[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,(width*height))]);
        }
    }
```

When I run the game, one of the 100 blocks has been destroyed, but then nothing happens. From my script, I was expecting one block to destroy every second, as defined by:
`yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeDestroy);`
where int timeDestroy = 1;

and repeat until all the blocks are gone - game over. How can I change my script so the 100 gameObjects are destroyed one after another, until none are left?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your `IEnumerator SelfDestruct();` in a while loop:

```
IEnumerator SelfDestruct()
{
    while (1<2)
    {
        Destroy(blockList[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, (width * height))]);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds( timeDestroy );
    } 
}
```

that way it will resume destroying the blocks, and you need to remove the `SelfDestruct();` in Update.

Ps. Thanks derHugo I have forgotten that ^^.

Comment: You mean `while(true)`? ^^ using `1<2` is the funniest way I have seen someone writing `true` so far ^^ also OP is still calling this each and every frame which is the main issue ;)

Comment: You need to use `StartCoroutine` in order to start it as a Coroutine .. this is still c# though and calling it without executes everything until the first `yield` statement -> still destroys the objects

Comment: Note that you will also have to remove the objects from the list otherwise you might try to destroy the same object twice

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues here

- you start a coroutine **once** but it doesn't really wait for anything (only at the end). There is no repetition anywhere. You probably wanted to use a loop there
- you call the `SelfDestruct` every frame within `Update` which will execute everything until the first `yield`!
- you potentially try to destroy the same object multiple times since you never remove them from your list.

Actually the entire thing can be one single coroutine!

I would also use [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) to randomize the order of blocks **once** and then simply iterate and destroy them one by one in already randomized order.

Something like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;
...

public class Wall : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject block;
    public int width = 10;
    public int height = 10;
    public int timeDestroy = 1;
    
    // Yes this is valid and Unity will automatically
    // run this as a Coroutine!
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // Don't even need this as a field only locally
        // already pre-allocate the needed amount
        var blockList = new List<GameObject>(height * width);

        for (var y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                var offset = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
                var newBlock = Instantiate(block, transform.position + offset, Quaternion.identity);
                blockList.Add(new Block);
            }
        }
        
        // shuffle the blocks once
        var randomizedBlocks = blockList.OrderBy(blockInstance => Random.value);
        // then simply iterate them in already randomized order
        foreach (var blockInstance in randomizedBlocks)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (timeDestroy);

            Destroy(blockInstance);
        }

        // Now you additionally also have direct control when they are all destroyed
        Debug.Log("All blocks have been destroyed!");
    }
}
```